# Not able to reset foreman admin password using foreman-rake

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, foreman

I am trying to migrate database to mysql from sqlite. Database migrated successfully using foreman-mysql2. After restarting foreman, I wasn't allowed to login with admin/changeme.

I then tried to reset password using the below command

```
foreman-rake permission-reset password=secret
```

But I am getting the below error

rake aborted!

Don't know how to build task 'permission:reset' (see --tasks)
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task_manager.rb:62:in `[]'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:149:in`invoke_task'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in`each'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in`run_with_threads'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in`block in run'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/share/foreman/vendor/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in`run'
/usr/bin/rake1.9.1:32:in `'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting answer for my own question

Its not permission.... 
Its **permissions**

when we get errors like this, just type `--tasks` at the end of the command and  see rake list, make sure the one you are trying exists in that list..,

correct command:

```
sudo foreman-rake permissions:reset PASSWORD=secret
```

On running the above command, its likely that you might get another error

```
ERF42-7495
"Cannot find user foreman_admin when switching context" or "Cannot find user foreman_api_admin when switching context"
```

To fix this, just type the below command

```
foreman-rake db:seed
```